As a C# noob, how do I retry WebClient.DownloadString funtion
I am AN ABSOLUTE C# NOOB, so this is my very first project. I am write a C% command line program that I input a URL it downloads images from a gallery website I frequent. 99% of the the code I have written works.  My only issue is sometimes my code, when trying to get the webpage source code, sometimes the download fails. 99% of what I am doing works. This 1% sometimes makes my program crash. I am trying to find a way to make WebClient.DownloadString will retry to download the page source if there is an error. With all that said above, 99% of the code is written, and working, so I will not rewrite it from the ground up in a different version of .net. (A suggestion I saw in a discord channel dedicated to C# coding that was not helpful in the least)
This is the code I have for downloading the page source:
static string getPageSource(string url)
{
  string pageSource = "";
  WebClient client = new WebClient();

  pageSource = client.DownloadString(url);
  if(pageSource.Length == 0)
    {
    pageSource = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
  return pageSource;
}

The code itself functions as is. Just whenever it fails, the app crashes.

Start by not using ALL CAPS in the question title, people take it as SHOUTING and don't read further.

This sounds like an X/Y problem.  Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. We can't help you with a crashing program if you can't tell us where it is crashing.

Obviously I the code I posted is the issue... Sometimes, when it tries to download the page source, it fails, and the entire app crashes. So I need to find a way to make "    pageSource = client.DownloadString(url);" repeat if it fails.

One thing you could do is implement some exception handling. See how you get on with that. Alternatively there is the Polly package, but that might be overkill for your scenario.

@YoItsTrev "the entire app cashes" in no way makes it obvious that it is crashing in that method. Generally, dotnet apps don't "crash", they throw exceptions and if those aren't properly handled, they exit in a more or less controlled fashion.

Note that an immediate retry is not always the correct response to a failure. That web site might be dropping your requests due to you exceeding a download limit, or because it's currently over-stress, or any kind of intervening network issue, that may or may not be a short-term transient.

WebClient is disposable. Don't forget to dispose it every time you use it. Not doing that could eventually cause a crash.

But why use WebClient at all, and not the newer HttpClient?

The first step is to always determine how the application is failing. To do that, you run it in a debugger. In your case, it's probably throwing an exception in the DownloadString method, so your second attempt is never being called.
It's just a guess, based on the limited information you've provided. Based on your post, you're apparently a newb to programming in general yes? You're obviously not thinking like a programmer yet, but we should expect that from newbs.
I recommend you follow the links in my comment to your original post and read those documents thoroughly. They will help you understand how to approach asking questions here. As for thinking like a programmer, always start with a careful read of the documentation for the API's you are using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=net-8.0
Take note of the exception list:

Exceptions ArgumentNullException The address parameter is null.
WebException The URI formed by combining BaseAddress and address is
invalid.
-or-
An error occurred while downloading the resource.
NotSupportedException The method has been called simultaneously on
multiple threads.

In your case, it's probably throwing WebException due to a server timeout or because it's denying you access. You may be exceeding a download limit.
Read up on how to catch exceptions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements
Place your code in a try/catch block:
    string getPageSource(string url)
    {
        var pageSource = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using var client = new WebClient();
            pageSource = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unexpeccted exception {ex.Message}");
        }

        return pageSource;
    }

Run that and tell us which exception is caught, then I'll show you how to properly do a limited number of retries.

NOTE: WebClient is obsolete and should not be used. If your instructor tells you to use it, then use it and smother it in comments about how good coders would not use and why.

I have seen a try in other stackoverflow posts, but isn't it irrelevant? Yes, it will handle the error, but it does not fix the issue. It will handle the error, but it does not fix the issue of making it try to download the page source again.

If you really want free help, stop arguing with the people who are trying to help you for free. Post the exception output when you have completed the task at hand. If it proves our assumptions, I'll show you how do retries properly. Not going to waste my time if that turns out not to be the incorrect solution.

I posted your code into mine, it crashes EVERY TIME I run it now.

"it crashes EVERY TIME I run it now" tells us nothing. Is it throwing an exception? Please post all of the exception text. Also, I updated the code block to include a using statement. I got it to compile, but I can't test it, because you never posted a minimal, reproducible example.

If you're not seeing console output from the catch blocks, then it's probably not throwing any exceptions there. That means it is crashing somewhere else, and we need to understand where and why.

How are you running this code? If you're launching it from an IDE, it could be that the console window is being torn down before you get a chance to read any output. Try opening a cmd shell and navigating to where the executable resides and run it by hand.

I got your code to work. It was giving a 404 error. I had to readd the a single line of code that I had not added to my code above:
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36");

I am still getting an error, but it is saying too many requests too fast, so I am gonna try to put a pause in it.

So it was an X/Y problem. This is why those of us who've hung around here a while, don't take "it crashes" at face value. It's why you need to learn to drill into the problem before you come here asking for help. Until you understand the actual failure, you don't really know what is wrong. Retrying the same errant processes would just give you more errors. That said, you can put that whole try/catch block into a counted loop with an embedded Thread.Sleep(n) call, where n increases on each subsequent retry. But you still have deal with failures.

Since network failures generally don't resolve in a matter of seconds, retries should usually start at tens of seconds, with some kind of message to the user, and then quickly back-off to minutes with the option for the user to cancel the operation. Or just leave it up to the user whether to retry at all, provided you've given them adequate information about the failure.

Your help, and the pause I added, have had zero crashes when running the program dozens of times without issue. Thanks for our help, I really appreciate it.

@YoItsTrev, thanks. Don't forget to mark this thread answered.
